# Grouping by date when datetime is given

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

In my table, I have some ID's associated with each Date. How do I count the number of ID's associated with a date ? The date column is in datetime, but I want to group by date and not date time.

Expected output -

```
11/14/2013, 30 counts
11/15/2013, 400 counts 
etc
```

I am using **SQL server 2000**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DateTimeCol), 0)` which truncates the time to midnight.

```
SELECT Date = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DateTimeCol), 0)
     , COUNT = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DateTimeCol), 0)
```

Comment: I only need to group by Date. But, I will try this query also. Thanks.